# ¿Cómo añadir varias cuenta atrás?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo un proyecto html y me vi algo obligada a usar scripts de JS. No controlo absolutamente nada de ello, y leo sobre el tema, y solo veo ejemplos prácticos sin explicación... En fin, que no entiendo nada.

Cogí este [código](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp) y lo apliqué a mi web. Todo funcionaba perfecto, pero el problema viene ahora.

Quiero tener varias cuentas atrás, por lo que "*Probé suerte*".

```css
#cuentaatras1 {
  color:red;
  }
#cuentaatras2 {
  color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
<p id="cuentaatras1"></p>
<p id="cuentaatras2"></p>
<script>

var countDownDate = new Date("Feb 10, 2020 22:40:00").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();

  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  document.getElementById("cuentaatras1").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("cuentaatras1").innerHTML = "Revisa la sección correspondiente";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>

<script>

var countDownDate = new Date("Feb 20, 2020 14:40:00").getTime();

var x = setInterval(function() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();

  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  document.getElementById("cuentaatras2").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("cuentaatras2").innerHTML = "Revisa la sección correspondiente";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
</html>
```

Aunque tenga definidas distintas fechas, sale la misma. Me esperaba que no funcionase, era demasiado simple, pero no se me ocurre nada más...

Comment: Hola! ¿Has probado a no llamar a las dos variables countDownDate? Quizá se te está haciendo un lio el js por eso, y te coge el valor asignado en segundo lugar.

Comment: Era eso! Ahora funciona bien ^^ Gracias!

Comment: Genial! Te pongo una respuesta para que me la aceptes!

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta @OscarGarcia lo siento!

Comment: No te preocupes nos pasa a todos al comienzo y, además, eso me trajo a tu pregunta ;) espero haber sido de ayuda.

Comment: ¡Totalmente! Muchas gracias ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo evitar repetir código en la medida de lo posible y encapsular la funcionalidad que deseas en una clase (por compatibilidad la he creado mediante una función).

En mi ejemplo he creado una clase con tres propiedades (`id`, `obj` y `fecha`) y un método (`calcular`) que son calculadas y enviada a `setInterval` durante la creación de la instancia de la clase.

Además, he hecho uso de los [atributos de datos `data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/como/Usando_atributos_de_datos) para reducir el número de parámetros del constructor y que sea más sencillo modificar las fechas en el mismo HTML, sin tener que buscar en javascript.

También se podría haber automatizado la llamada al constructor por cada elemento buscado por selector con `querySelectorAll()`.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo encapsular la funcionalidad para reducir código:

```js
function Temporizador(id) {
  /* Obtenemos datos útiles que no se modificarán */
  this.id = id;
  this.obj = document.getElementById(id);
  this.fecha = new Date(this.obj.dataset.fecha).getTime();
  /* Implementamos el cálculo de la diferencia de tiempo */
  this.calcular = function() {
    let ahora = new Date().getTime();
    let diferencia = this.fecha - ahora;
    let inicio = 'Faltan ';
    if (diferencia < 0) {
      diferencia = -diferencia;
      inicio = 'Han pasado ';
    }
    /* Convertimos las milésimas de segundo en segundos */
    let segundos = Math.round(diferencia / 1000);
    let minutos = Math.round(segundos / 60);
    segundos %= 60;
    segundos = ('0' + segundos).substr(-2);
    let horas = Math.round(minutos / 60);
    minutos %= 60;
    minutos = ('0' + minutos).substr(-2);
    let días = Math.round(horas / 24);
    horas %= 24;
    horas = ('0' + horas).substr(-2);
    this.obj.innerHTML = inicio + días + "d " + horas + "h " +
      minutos + "m " + segundos + "s";
  };
  /* Esta es la parte más compleja debido a cómo trata los ámbitos
    javascript: llamamos a setInterval pasando como parámetro
    esta instancia (this) a una función inmediata que devuelve
    una función que llama a "calcular()" */
  setInterval(
    ( (self) => { return () => self.calcular(); } )(this),
    1000
  );
  /* Hacemos una primera llamada para mostrar el valor inicial */
  this.calcular();
};

/* Ahora reutilizar tu código es mucho más sencillo buscando únicamente
  los elementos que tengan el atributo "data-fecha" */
document.querySelectorAll('[data-fecha]').forEach(
  (elemento) => new Temporizador(elemento.id)
);
```

```css
#cuentaatras1 {
  color: red;
}
#cuentaatras2 {
  color: blue;
}
#cuentaatras3 {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<p id="cuentaatras1" data-fecha="Feb 1, 2020 22:40:00"></p>
<p id="cuentaatras2" data-fecha="2020-02-20 14:40:00"></p>
<p id="cuentaatras3" data-fecha="2021-01-01 00:00:00"></p>
```

Comment: He agregado soporte para que muestre un texto diferente si ha llegado o no la fecha establecida, para evitar la aparición de números negativos.

Answer (score 0):

Calculas el tiempo restante utilizando la misma variable `countDownDate` y `js` se está haciendo un lio con ello.

Utiliza una variable para cada cuenta atrás y funcionará como esperas.

Comment: Si añadieses un snniped con tu solución funcionando sería perfecto. Piensa que de esa manera sería más útil para alguien que buscase hacer 2 **cuenta atrás**, pudiendo copiar y pegar el código funcionando ^^